# Generate automatically DataTable from an XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing, linq-to-xml

Is there any possibility to automatically populate the dataTable from an XML document ?

By automatically, I mean, autogenerate rows/columns.

Example an XML to use :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:factures xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://XXX" xsi:schemaLocation="xxxxx.xsd">
<facture num="F0000047672" numArchivage="000" dateCompostage="2016-04-14" numCompostage="20160414000333" numTVAIntracom="FR09429449457" nomFournisseur="TT" numCommande="09457519" societeFacturee="005" typeFacture="FAC" montantHT="3817.920" montantTTC="4027.910" montantTVA="209.990" devise="EUR" dateFacture="2016-04-04" dateEcheance="2016-05-31" CodeSiteLivraison="630N" factureDetaillee="false" nomFichier="KKK_005_20160414_000333.pdf">
    <ligneTVA tauxTVA="5.500" montantHT="3817.920" montantTVA="209.990" montantTTC="4027.910" />
</facture>
<facture num="970928" numArchivage="000" dateCompostage="2016-04-14" numCompostage="20160414000365" numTVAIntracom="FR64482283694" nomFournisseur="jfjfjfj" numCommande="02090828" societeFacturee="005" typeFacture="FAC" montantHT="28623.980" montantTTC="34348.780" montantTVA="5724.800" devise="EUR" dateFacture="2016-04-11" dateEcheance="2016-06-10" CodeSiteLivraison="02K" factureDetaillee="false" nomFichier="KKK_005_20160414_000365.pdf">
    <ligneTVA tauxTVA="20.000" montantHT="28623.980" montantTVA="5724.800" montantTTC="34348.780" />
</facture>
</tns:factures>
```

As you can see, there is a "facture" node and a "LigneTVA" node.

I would like to add these two nodes automatically in a dataTable without specifying each column.

Is this possible ?

Using Linq-to-SQL? Or something else?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication22
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try ASAP :) So the trick is to use a Dataset instead a DataTable ?

Comment: Using DataSet or DataTable depends on the number of layers of Tags.  With DataSet the first layer tag is the DataSet Name.  Second layer tag is the DataTable Name.  Third Layer are the columns names.  Fourth layer are the values associated with the third layer tags.  A DataTable solution you loose the DataSet name.  Also DataTable fails to Write XML unless your DataTable has a name.  DataSet will write xml even when the DataSet doesn't have a name.

Comment: I tried your code, and it's ok ! Very nice ! Thanks guys :)